# JSON formatting between "pretty" and "condensed"?

Tags: json

Most JSON parsers have the option to generate a JSON-structured string as either "normal" (no extra whitespace) or "pretty" (whitespace added for easier human-readability).

The "pretty" version expands out objects and arrays into each property having its own line. But when an object is composed of a few short properties and values, it's even more legible to have it all on one line.

Basically, I'm looking for a formatter that does a "half-collapsed" formatting; where if the JSON object to be formatted fits well on one line, it doesn't get expanded out.

For example, given a JSON structure that if it were printed "pretty" it would be:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "circle",
    "position": {
      "x": 100,
      "y": 100
    },
    "color": "red",
    "label": "Big Red",
    "radius": 50
  },
  {
    "type": "point",
    "position": {
      "x": 100,
      "y": 100
    }
  }
]
```

instead I want:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "circle",
    "position": { "x": 100, "y": 100 },
    "color": "red",
    "label": "Big Red",
    "radius": 50
  },
  { "type": "point", "position": { "x": 100, "y": 100 }}
]
```

The whole "point" object is short enough that it can fit comfortably on one line, so it is presented that way. The "circle" object would be too long to fit on one line, but the sub-object of its "position" can be.

Is there a term for this "half-collapsed", "human-friendly, focused on paragrph-style line lengths" formatting? Any formatter or code-linting tool provide this sort of output?

Comment: What if you have another nested object like this?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't meant for question seeking software recommendations, consider asking this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/